# Python : fork and exec a process to run on different terminal

Tags: python, process

I am trying to simulate a a network consisting of several clients and servers. I have written node.py which contains client-server code. I want to run multiple instances node.py. But I don't want to do it manually so I have written another file spawn.py which spawns multiple instances of node.py using fork and exec. However, I need to run each instance of node.py on different terminal(shell) so that I can easily debug what is happening inside each node. 
How can we do that? Please help.

EDIT : I am working on linux and using python 2.5 and 
       I want to run all processes on the same box

Comment: "run each instance of node.py on different terminal(shell)"  Please show how you would do this "manually" from the command line or with a shell script.  I'm unclear on what you're talking about.

Comment: @Lott , if i want to start 3 nodes , I type 'python node.py <port-no>' on 3 different terminals.  I want to do the same thing either using shell script or using another python program spawn.py.

Comment: @atv: So you can't do this from a single terminal manually?  You can't use RSH or SSH or PUTTY to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "real" (pseudo-;-) terminals, and are using X11 (almost every GUI interface on Linux does;-), you could exec `xterm -e python node.py` instead of just `python node.py` -- substitute for `xterm` whatever terminal emulator program you prefer, of course (I'm sure they all have command-line switches equivalent to good old xterm's `-e`, to specify what program they should run!-).

Comment: @alex , thanks a lot .. but one more problem
xterm -e python.py just opens single terminal

if i write a shell script like this
xterm -e python.py 101 
xterm -e python.py 102

it opens only 1 terminal waits for the prog to finish and then opens second terminal :( How to open all terminals at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

```
shell #1:
for p in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    python node.py > $p.log 2>&1
done


shell #2:
tail -F 1.log 

shell #3:
tail -F 2.log 

etc...
```